# Is it possible to filter properties available on an interface by using one of the interfaces it implements?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

**Background:**

I'm not sure exactly how to phrase this question, so this is the example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public interface IEverythingVM : IA, IB
{
    MyTypeA {get;}
    MyTypeB {get;}
    MyTypeC {get;}

    MyTypeD {get;}
    MyTypeE {get;}
    MyTypeF {get;}
}

public class EverythingVM : IEverythingVM
{
    // Populate everything from MyTypeA to MyTypeF
}

public interface IA
{
    MyTypeA {get;}
    MyTypeB {get;}
    MyTypeC {get;}
}


public interface IB
{
    MyTypeD {get;}
    MyTypeE {get;}
    MyTypeF {get;}
}
```

**Realisation:**

I was under the impression that I could do something like the following, but having written it out, it's planely apparent why it won't work - I'm trying to take something big, debigulate it and then *rebigulate* it, which is a concept so ridiculous it makes me want to laugh out loud and chortle.

```
{
    IA varIA = new EverythingVM(param1, param2);
    IB varIB = new EverythingVM(param1, param2);

    var cm = new ComparisonManager(varIA, varIB);        
}

public class ComparisonManager
{
    public ComparisonManager(IEverythingVM varEIA, IEverythingVM varEIB)
    {
        // be able to acces MyTypeA, MyTypeB & MyTypeC from varEIA
        // be able to acces MyTypeD, MyTypeE & MyTypeF from varEIB
    }
}
```

**Question**:

Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is that in some cases I want `MyTypeA`, `MyTypeB` & `MyTypeC` available in `ComparisonManager`, and in other cases I want `MyTypeD`, `MyTypeE` & `MyTypeF` available in `ComparisonManager`. Is there any way for me to achieve this given the current structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out the solution was to:

```
public class ComparisonManager<T>
{
    private readonly T _diskServiceVm;
    private readonly T _panelServiceVm;

    public ComparisonManager(T diskServiceVm, T panelServiceVm)
    {
        _diskServiceVm = diskServiceVm;
        _panelServiceVm = panelServiceVm;
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
if (/* circumstance A */)
{
    IA varIA = new A(varA, varB);
    IA varIB = new B(varA, varB);

    // this knows how to deal with MyTypeA, MyTypeB & MyTypeC
    var comparisonManager = new ComparisonManager<IA>(varIA , varIB);
}
else
{
    IB varIA = new A(varA, varB);
    IB varIB = new B(varA, varB);

    // this knows how to deal with MyTypeD, MyTypeE & MyTypeF
    var comparisonManager = new ComparisonManager<IB>(varIA , varIB);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do like this:

```
public class ComparisonManager
{
    public ComparisonManager(IA varEIA, IB varEIB) {}
}
```

?